# Primefaces Submit button of SelectOneButton does not work

Tags: button, primefaces, radio-button, submit

As i am a newcomer for primefaces framework i tried to use SelectOneButton component with nearly the same code on primefaces.org's demo however i couldnt manage to get it work.
When i click on the submit button i cant see any result.
Below is my code for my xhtml and bean files. Any help is appreciated mostly. Thanks.

soru.xhtml file: (located under Webcontent/faces folder)

```html
 <h:form id="form">

 <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

        <h:outputText value="Options: " />
        <p:selectOneButton value="#{buttonBean.number}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
        </p:selectOneButton>

    </h:panelGrid>


    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"/>

    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{buttonBean.number}" />


</h:form>
```

ButtonBean.java file:

```java
package com.ali.deneme;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.util.UUID;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ButtonBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * my ButtonBean class file - Ali Kerim Erkan
     */

    private Integer number;

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


}
```

My web.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>deneme</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- <welcome-file>/faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file> -->
        <!-- <welcome-file>/faces/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.xhtml</welcome-file> -->
        <welcome-file>./faces/soru.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: did you try assigning a value to number? for example `private Integer number = 1`;

Comment: yes I tried this too but it doesn't help. I also tried to change wrapper object 'Integer number' to prmitive type 'int number' but it didnt work out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @stg mentioned use

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

and also you are mapping two url-pattern to FacesServlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Remove mapping with '/faces/*' pattern and use mapping with '*.xhtml' pattern when calling your url.

example: http://example.com/page.xhtml

and please dont use **faces** as a directory name because it is not a good directory name for a JSF app.

**faces** is a common url pattern since first days of jsf.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Those solved my trivial but time consuming problem @Mindwin

Comment: @alikerimerkan glad it helped. if an answer is helpful to you please upvote and accept it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong import. Instead of

```
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
```

you have to use

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

Comment: I tried ur your solution but it gives the following error on browser page:  Cycle Detected
Description: Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle.

Comment: The import in a Java class would not cause a cycle in the browser. Google your error message.